# How to tell VSCode/TypeScript window.Service exists?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I use `jsCheck` setting in VS Code, and it uses TypeScript to verify my code.
There is a global service which is set by the code which is generated on back-end side (yep, legacy), and it is referenced in many places `Service.get(...);`

How can I tell Typescript to trust me that the service exists and has a particular contract?
Do I have to create `d.ts` file for that? Can this be achieved with JSDoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to create d.ts file for that?

Yes. Just create a global `.d.ts` (any `.d.ts` file that has no top-level `import` or `export` is a global file), and declare your global variable:

```
// global.d.ts

declare const Service: {
  get(): any // etc
}
```